# Ajax - JSON Response is not reading well an array of ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './checkcolors.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        url: '<?php echo $LINK;?>',
        SizeId: SelectedSizeID
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {                             
                alert(data.colorids);

        });
    }
});
```

The result from checkcolors.php comes like this:

```
{"colorids":["24604603","24604684","24604640","24604609","24604682","24604686","24604681","24604689","24604602","24604679","24604680","24604622","24604685","24604683","24604621","24604677","24604688"]}
```

When the Ajax post method is called the alert function is giving **ONE** result instead of many with single id in it.

The result from the alert is single and it is like this:

```
24604603,24604684,24604640,24604609,24604682,24604686,24604681,24604689,24604602,24604679,24604680,24604622,24604685,24604683,24604621,24604677,24604688
```

I think somehow my code is not reading the json correctly. Can you help me out resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just apply your `$.each` to the `data.colorids` Array instead of the wrapping `data` Object:

```
$.each(data.colorids, function(index, element) {                             
    alert(element);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = {"colorids":["24604603","24604684","24604640","24604609","24604682","24604686","24604681","24604689","24604602","24604679","24604680","24604622","24604685","24604683","24604621","24604677","24604688"]};

$.each(data.colorids, function(index, element){
    console.log(element);
    // Open your console (don't want everybody to be bothered with tons of alerts)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript automatically formats arrays like that when they're put in an environment where they cannot represented as literal arrays.  So your code is still an array, it's just not being formatted how you want it to...

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to have your JavaScript array be formatted as an array, but represented as a string in the memory, here is an example:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.colorids));
```

---

Here is an example representing how your data is still a valid array, just being represented differently:

```
var myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
alert(myArray); // foo,bar
myArray[0]; // 'foo'
```

---

Based on [**@blex**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170710/3117575)'s asnwer, I may have misunderstood the result you wanted.

You have to iterate through the array to get the individual values, this can be done multiple ways.

Just so I'm not copying blex's answer, you can use the native alternative  [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
data.colorids.forEach(function(color){
  alert(color);
});
```